# not able to source R file

Tags: python, osx-yosemite, rpy2

I am trying to use rpy2 library in python.

In the below code I am trying to source a r file in a python script.

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro
y=ro.r.source("r file")
```

I am getting the below error message.
I am using osx yosemite 10.10.4.

```
    anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/robject.py:6: UserWarning: Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.2_1/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/grDevices/libs/grDevices.so':
  dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.2_1/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/grDevices/libs/grDevices.so, 6): Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
  Expected in: /Users/zopper/anaconda/lib//libJPEG.dylib
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO

  rpy2.rinterface.initr()
/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/robject.py:6: UserWarning: In addition: 
  rpy2.rinterface.initr()
/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/robject.py:6: UserWarning: Warning message:

  rpy2.rinterface.initr()
/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/robject.py:6: UserWarning: package ‘grDevices’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found 

  rpy2.rinterface.initr()
/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/robject.py:6: UserWarning: package ‘graphics’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found 

  rpy2.rinterface.initr()
/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/robject.py:6: UserWarning: During startup - 
  rpy2.rinterface.initr()
/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/robject.py:6: UserWarning: Warning messages:

  rpy2.rinterface.initr()
/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/robject.py:6: UserWarning: 1: package ‘stats’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found
```

**EDIT**

*adding result of*

```
otool -L /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO

/System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO:
    /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 4.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics (compatibility version 64.0.0, current version 600.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 48.0.0)
    /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleVPA.framework/Versions/A/AppleVPA (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 1153.18.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 62.0.0)
    /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleJPEG.framework/Versions/A/AppleJPEG (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libJPEG.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libTIFF.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libPng.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libGIF.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libJP2.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libRadiance.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 228.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.5)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/IOSurface.framework/Versions/A/IOSurface (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1213.0.0)
```

Comment: `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall  rpy2`

Comment: still get the same erro

Comment: Collecting singledispatch (from rpy2)
  Using cached singledispatch-3.4.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: six, singledispatch, rpy2                            Found existing installation: six 1.9.0
DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (six) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact @cel that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
 ........
.........
.........
Successfully installed rpy2-2.7.2 singledispatch-3.4.0.3 six-1.10.0

Comment: No, this is due to the fact that you are mixing conda and pip. What happens if you do `pip uninstall rpy2`, `conda uninstall rpy2`, `pip install rpy2`?

Comment: `conda uninstall rpy2`
Fetching package metadata: ....
Error: no packages found to remove from environment: //anaconda

Comment: `pip uninstall rpy2 `      Uninstalling rpy2-2.7.2:
  /anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2-2.7.2.dist-info/DESCRIPTION.rst
  /anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2-2.7.2.dist-info/METADATA

Comment: @cel   Then I again installed rpy2 using pip.      It throws the same error.

Comment: Can you add the output of `otool -L /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO` to your question?

Comment: @cel :  added as edit to the question

Comment: and the output of `echo $DYLIB_DYLOAD`?

Comment: `LP-19s-MBP:~ zer$ echo $DYLIB_DYLOAD`

`LP-19s-MBP:~ zer$`    its nothing

Comment: I am running out of ideas. The point here is that somehow `/System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO` loads `/Users/zopper/anaconda/lib//libJPEG.dylib`, altough it seems to be properly linked against system's library. No idea why this happens, tough.

Comment: Still have this issue.